# A SPARQL Query to get my pizza's name

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, protege, topbraid-composer

I am just a beginner in SPARQL and can write some basic queries. I have a pizza ontology in which there is one pizza whose properties are as follows:

```
rdf:subClassOf NamedPizza

hasTopping only (MozzarellaTopping
              or PeperoniSausageTopping
              or TomatoTopping)

hasTopping some MozzarellaTopping

hasTopping some PeperoniSausageTopping

hasTopping some TomatoTopping
```

i have written the following query, but it gives no result.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassof [
    owl:onProperty :hasTopping;
    owl:someValuesFrom :MozzarellaTopping ] .
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassof [
    owl:onProperty :hasTopping;
    owl:someValuesFrom :PeperonSausageTopping ] .
  ?pizza rdfs:subClassof [
    owl:onProperty :hasTopping;
    owl:someValuesFrom :TomatoTopping ] .
}
```

What is the SPARQL query to get the name of this pizza?

i am using Protege 4.2 as well as TopBraid to run the SPARQL query

Answer (score 4):

In your SPARQL query you write `rdfs:subClassof` instead of `rdfs:subClassOf` ('o' instead of 'O'). Capitalisation matters, because the prefix notation is just shorthand for URIs and in URIs different characters (like lowercase instead of uppercase) make a different URI.

Answer (score 2):

Cut the query down until it is yielding something, then look to see why the part you have removed is not matching the data.